# Tagging Markfast

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm using Markfast as below

**Script:**

```
WORDLIST PARTICLESLIST = 'NameswithParticles.txt';
DECLARE PARTICLES;
Document{ -> MARKFAST(PARTICLES, PARTICLESLIST,true)};
```

**NameswithParticles.txt:**

```
der
Der
de
De
d'
D'
De la
de La 
de la
von
Von
van
Van
ten
La
la
Le
le
L'
St
Al
al
O'
```

**Sample Input :**

```
1.der Waals radius
2.van Minh
3.Der Brul
4.de Brul
```

It tags all the above particle names except der and Der.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I get four `PARTICLES` annotations. If `MARKFAST` misses matches, there are most likely whitespaces in the txt file in my experience.

Comment: @PeterKluegl,I tried the above question. I also faced the same issue

Comment: Which version of UIMA Ruta do you use? (I used 2.5.0)

Comment: Yes I'm also used UIMA Ruta (2.5.0)

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea yet what the problem might be. Is there maybe something special about the DocumentAnnotation?

Comment: Sorry For me its BOM issue.Now I'm also getting four PARTICLES

Comment: Whether the WORDLIST given above is what you are using or Its a sample Wordlist?

Comment: If its a sample file Pls update the wordlist. This issue  may also cause due to  Whitespace.

Comment: I have Updated the WORDLIST

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its due to Whitespace. So active the dictRemoveWS in configuration parameter.View the comments for more details  [Wordlist -uima ruta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341007/wordlist-uima-ruta)

Comment: How to Configure  dictRemoveWS in the Script itself

Comment: This is an open issue. There is no way to set this by rules, only in the configuration parameters